# GPS location and city name using TerraService or other

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, gps

I have a simple app that is retrieving the current location via GPS and displays my current location. The problem is that the web service I'm using for getting the city name ([TerraService](http://msrmaps.com/TerraService2.asmx)) doesn't work with non English characters.
Also I want to be able to customize the format of the returned data. Now it can give me "1km SW Bart, Redmond, United States" and thats not good.
Do you know how to customize it and get it to work with non English characters?

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher myGPS;
myGPS = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(); 
myGPS.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(myGPS_PositionChanged);
myGPS.Start();



void myGPS_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e) 
    {

        double  myLatitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;    //do what you want with myLatitude and myLongtitude 
        double myLongtitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;

        GPSServiceReference.TerraServiceSoapClient client = new GPSServiceReference.TerraServiceSoapClient();

        client.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted += new EventHandler<GPSServiceReference.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompletedEventArgs>(client_ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceCompleted);

        client.ConvertLonLatPtToNearestPlaceAsync(new GPSServiceReference.LonLatPt { Lat = myLatitude, Lon = myLongtitude });
    }
```

Comment: Turned out that the Bing map SOAP Service was far better and allowed be to customize the returned data in a great way. It also handled non English characters.

Comment: It would have been nice, if you provided your findings as an answer to your own question :-D